# GitHub: uploading existing libraries

Tags: github

Should I re-upload an existing library to my GitHub repo if my code uses it? Or should I only reference the library?

I have some Python programs that use the Yowsup library, which is [already on GitHub](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup). Should I upload my copy of this library with my code in order to make my code easier to understand, or should I just tell people to download Yowsup from its own GitHub page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain your dependencies using a dependency manager.

For Python code, this usually means using [`pip`](https://github.com/pypa/pip) to maintain a [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files):

```
pip install yowsup
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Commit the `requirements.txt` file to your repository. Don't commit the `yowsup` code itself.

Now other users can clone your repository and install all of your project's dependencies using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Generally you will want to do this inside a virtual environment, which in the Python world generally means using [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) (and optionally [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)).

Many other languages have similar tools, so you can apply the same general technique.